# How to dynamically call data from an API when option is selected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose there are two hotels in my options in select tags and I want my h1 to change when I select one of the options. How do I achieve this

I am using POST method to authorize and call data in my reservationCtrl and display the hotel_name in my select tags.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class = "row" ng-controller="reservationCtrl">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Select a Hotel:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option ng-repeat="x in hotels.data">{{x.hotel_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And I am using GET method to call data from another API to display the hotel_name.

```
        <div class="row" ng-controller="showCtrl">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 ng-repeat="x in hotel.data">{{x.hotel_name}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my showController and I want my hotel id to change like from 72 to 35 when I click one of the options so that it will call data from a different API and display a different name in the headers.

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module("reservationModule")
        .controller("showCtrl", function($http, $scope, $log){


                    $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: '&hotel_id=72'})
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.hotel = response.data;
                        }, function (reason){
                            $scope.error = reason.data;
                            $log.info(reason);
                        });
         });


})();
```

Here is the reservationController

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module("reservationModule")
        .controller("reservationCtrl", function($http, $scope, $log){

             $http({
        url: '',
        method: "POST",
        data: 'postData',
        headers:{ 'Authorization': 'value'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            $scope.hotels = response.data;
        }
    );
         });


})();
```

Comment: you can do this onChange event of select option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add ng-change and achieve your functionality as below

**JS code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.hotels = [{
      name: 'Taj',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Royal',
      id: 2
    }];
    $scope.hotelInfo = {};
    $scope.fetchData = function() {
      // here call service which will fetch data and assign to hotel data
      $scope.hotelInfo = {
        address: 'London'
      };
    }

  });

  app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = ''

  });
```

**HTML code**

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
      <select ng-options='item as item.name for item in hotels' ng-model='hotel' ng-change='fetchData()'>
      </select>
      {{hotel}} - {{hotelInfo}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the link [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1ehvs0wn/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call event on the select box which will call simple function which return the data like following

```
    <select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes" 
   ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
```

write javascript code on the update function

Answer (score 0):

Your can use ng-change on select of particular hotel.

```js
In congroller : 

$scope.showHotel = function(hotelName){
   $scope.selectedHotel = hotelName;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="showCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <h1 ng-repeat="x in hotel.data" ng-change="showHotel(x.hotel_name)">{{x.hotel_name}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

In view you you can edit like this if you have to display only one hotel name instead of ng-repeat:

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="showCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>{{selectedHotel}}</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```